# Why can't I build in Xcode after I changed the name of my ionic app in my config.xml file?

Tags: xcode, ionic-framework

I have recently submitted my first version of my ionic app into the app store. I realized that I forgot to change the name of my app in the config.xml  tag. After I made the change my Xcode refuses to build my app. Do I need to make more changes other than what I did in my config.xml file?

Comment: You say "refused".  Is there an error message?

Comment: No error's, I can't select the build button. @tkoenig

Comment: Check the project's scheme settings… it may not be able to find its executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KSums answer above is correct, although the commands have changed. They are now:

ionic platform remove ios

ionic platform add ios

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what the hold up was but I removed the platforms and then reinstalled them and that seemed to do the trick!

ionic platforms remove ios

ionic platforms add ios